# Tela que atualiza horário automaticamente flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state

Good afternoon

I'm trying to run a test application from code

When I extend the State it gives an error in the code call and when I extend the **StatelessWidget** it does not give an error in the call but it gives an error in my **'StateMyApp'**. coloquei State Myapp mais é . Quando eu coloco entre as <> a palavra some

**where do i call the code**

```
return Stack(
     fit: StackFit.loose,
     children: [
    PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes(),
```

**Error adding StatelessWidget**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes createState() => PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes();
}

class PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes extends StatelessWidget{
  String _timeString;
```

**[Error giving State][3]**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes createState() => PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes();
}

class PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes extends State<MyApp>{
  String _timeString;
```

}

Comment: please write your error message in English.

Comment: *Using extends State<MyAPP>*

 The element type 'PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'. 


*Using extends StatelessWidget* 

extends StatelessWidget ('PlaceholderHorarioMarcacoes Function()') isn't a valid override of 'StatefulWidget.createState' ('State<StatefulWidget> Function()')